# JavaScript Symbols

Tags: javascript, oop, object, symbols

Yesterday I've learned symbols in js ,and I've used them to make object with  two same propertys 
ex:

```
const bowl = {
  [Symbol('apple')]: { color: 'red', weight: 136.078 },
  [Symbol('banana')]: { color: 'yellow', weight: 183.15 },
  [Symbol('orange')]: { color: 'orange', weight: 170.097 },
  [Symbol('banana')]: { color: 'yellow', weight: 176.845 }
};
```

But the question is how can I make this object using constructor function(s)??How I represent symbols in a constructor function??
Thanks!

Comment: Where's a [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) in your code? I don't see one. What do you mean by _using constructor functions_? All you've posted is an object literal that will have an apple, an orange and a single banana with a weight of 176.845

Comment: I don't see one too

Comment: @J add relevant code

Comment: *"I've used them to make object with two same propertys"* No, you haven't. :-) The object quoted doesn't use Symbol-named properties, and has only three properties; and you can't use Symbols to create an object with two properties with the same name. (You can use Symbols to create an object where two of the properties have different Symbol names with the same description, but they're different names.) Suggested reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Comment: Oh ,I've copy and paste the wrong code :(

Comment: If you make such a relevant edit in the original code you should specify that clearly or the other comments look totally nonsense until looking at your edits.

Comment: @J.Doe Why do you want to use symbols at all? How would your constructor look without symbols, can you show that please?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use symbol objects as object keys.

https://www.hacksparrow.com/object-as-javascript-objects-key.html